# Keyboard shortcuts in Turbo Pascal 3.0?

Tags: dos, turbo-pascal

I have the free download version of **Turbo Pascal 3.02** (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20792) and it works great to compile my old code in **Turbo Pascal 2.0**.
Trying to figure out how to use the build-in editor. Anyone remember any keyboard shortcuts or knows of online documentation?

Just being able to save and exit the editor would probably be enough, but I can't even figure out that much.

UPDATE: The link provided by @Glassfrog was very helpful. Here are the keys from that file that worked for me also in MS-DOS Turbo Pascal 3.02:

```
Character left: (arrow)
Character right: (arrow)
Word left: CTRL-A
Word right: CTRL-F
Line up: CTRL-E (or arrow)
Line down: CTRL-X (or arrow)
Scroll up: CTRL-W
Scroll down: CTRL-Z
Page up: CTRL-R
Page down: CTRL-C
To left on line: CTRL-Q CTRL-S
To right of line: CTRL-Q CTRL-D
To top of page: CTRL-Q CTRL-E
To bottom of page: CTRL-Q CTRL-X
To top of file: CTRL-Q CTRL-R
To end of file: CTRL-Q CTRL-C
To beginning of block: CTRL-Q CTRL-B
To end of block: CTRL-Q CTRL-K
To last cursor position: CTRL-Q CTRL-P
Insert mode on/off: CTRL-V
Insert line: CTRL-N
Delete line: CTRL-Y
Delete to end of line: CTRL-Q CTRL-Y
Delete right word: CTRL-T
Delete character under cursor: Ctrl-G (or delete)
Delete left character: (backspace
Mark block begin: CTRL-K CTRL-B
Mark block end: CTRL-K CTRL-K
Mark single word: CTRL-K CTRL-T
Hide/display block: CTRL-K CTRL-H
Copy block: CTRL-K CTRL-C
Move block: CTRL-K CTRL-V
Delete block: CTRL-K CTRL-Y
Read block from disk: CTRL-K CTRL-R
Write block to disk: CTRL-K CTRL-W
End edit: CTRL-K D
Tab: CTRL-I (or tab)
Auto tab on/off (Indent): CTRL-Q CTRL-I
Restore line: CTRL-Q CTRL-L
Find: CTRL-Q CTRL-F
Find & replace: CTRL-Q CTRL-A
Repeat last find: CTRL-L
Control character prefix: CTRL-P
```

Comment: Vaguely remembered something about ctrl-k. Experimenting a bit I figured out a few combos:
ctrl-k ctrl-d: exit (and save?)
ctrl-k ctrl-b: begin/end selection
ctrl-k ctrl-c: paste (clone?) selection
ctrl-k r: read block from file
ctrl-k t: select word
I'm sure there are many, many more.

Comment: The ctrl-k and ctrl-o ones are called wordstar keybindings. Still supported by Delphi and Lazarus.   The *nix editor Joe also uses them (but with some variations from the borland ones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CTRL-K  D**  will make you leave the editor

Also look at this online document: 
[Turbo Pascal Reference Manual Version 3.0](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_pascal/TURBO_Pascal_Reference_Manual_CPM_Version_3_Dec88.pdf)
It's CP/M edition manual but i think it will be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> Try these

1. `Alt + x`   (exit)
2. `F2`   (save)
3. `F3`   (open)
4. `Ctr + F9`   (run)
5. `Alt + F9`   (compile)
6. `Ctrl + Insert`   (copy)
7. `Ctrl + Delete`   (delete)
8. `Shift + Insert`   (paste)
9. `Shift + Delete`   (cut)